# DBTransaction closing when used for another method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, transactions

I am trying to use a single transaction for multiple different insert/update statements in my entity framework repository, however whenever I pass the transaction to a different method it is returned as closed, see below -

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
objectContext.Connection.Open();
DbTransaction transaction = objectContext.Connection.BeginTransaction();

using (transaction)
{
      IPersonRepository personRepository = new PersonRepository();
      context.Entry(person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
      personRepository.Update(person, objectRetrievedDateTime, transaction, objectContext);

      if (existingStatus != null)
      {
           objectContext.CreateObjectSet<tblPersonStatus>().Attach(existingStatus);
           existingStatus.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
           context.Entry(existingStatus).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

           IPersonStatusesRepository repository = new PersonStatusesRepository();
           repository.Update(existingStatus, objectRetrievedDateTime, transaction, objectContext);
      }
}
```

By the time the 1st update method is finished (personRepository.Update), the transaction has an error of "base {System.SystemException} = {"This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable."}"

Is there any way to get around this?

EDIT - The update method which is called looks like this -

```
public virtual void Update(T entity, DateTime? objectRetrievedDateTime, DbTransaction transaction, ObjectContext objectContext)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot update a null entity.");
        }

        using (transaction)
        {
            ObjectStateEntry entry = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity);

            string entityName = entity.GetType().Name;

            if (!objectRetrievedDateTime.HasValue || !this.AuditsAfterRetieval(objectRetrievedDateTime, entityName, entity))
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> oldValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                Dictionary<string, object> newValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                bool changed = this.EntityHasChanged(entity, entry, out oldValues, out newValues);

                // Check for changes before saving
                if (changed)
                {
                    this.context.SaveChanges();
                    this.Audit(entity, entityName, "Update", oldValues, newValues, false, null);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Object cannot be saved as it has been amended in another thread");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are committing the transaction somewhere else in your code, but without see it none can tell..

Comment: in your update method you are commiting the transaction

Comment: I have added the update method in the original post, I have also checked any other methods which are called, none of them commit the transaction.

Comment: @user1948635 the second update into the using statement  throw the exception?

Comment: Suprisingly the exception is not actually thrown until I call rollback (after several updates), is there any way to keep the transaction open when I exit the update method?

Comment: @user1948635 your update method code is wrong: you cannot put the transaction into 2 nested using statement

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so I dont need the using statement inside the update method? Would this know to use the using in the parent method?

Comment: @user1948635 yes, it is enought to use only one using statement for the transaction and then inside all the update method you want to use that transaction. when you reach the closing brace of the using statement the transaction will be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the using statement inside your Update method

You are disposing the transaction inside it with using

this is a quick stub to how you should use transaction

```
using(DbConnection connection = ...)    
{    
    connection.Open();    
    using(DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(...))    
    {
      try{
        ... update ...
        ... another update ...

        transaction.Commit(); 
      }catch(Exception){
       // transaction rolled back here if an Exception is thrown before the call to Commit()
        transaction.Rollback()
      }   
    }     
} // connection closed here
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this construct :

```
using (transaction)
{
   ...

  Update(transaction, ....)
}
```

When you exit from it, transaction is [Disposed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf2cw321.aspx), so also becomes invalid.

Comment: Suprisingly the exception is not actually thrown until I call rollback, is there any way to keep the transaction open when I exit the update method?

Comment: do not enclose it in *using* statement, or move it outside of this method.